# Undefined Index in PHP Code

Tags: php, variables, indexing, undefined

I am getting an undefined index error on this line of code:

```
switch ($_REQUEST["___p"])
```

I think I would need to declare the variable.  What would I change the above line to?

Comment: Hi @u_mulder, happy holidays :]

Comment: Simply there is not such an index inside the get or post array

Answer (score -1):

Either make sure exists beforehand with `isset()` or just ignore it:

```
switch (@$_REQUEST["___p"])
```